# clarification of "Section a line in Arcmap from a known point"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, point

[image]

Prior to my previous question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217031/section-a-line-in-arcmap-from-a-known-point

This point represents where a gas pipeline crosses a river (or road, rail for other points). The length of this crossing is given as 8 metres. The other point crossings vary from 1 - 100metres.

I want to split the lines so that lengths of crossings are shown as new line sections. So from this point, a new line section would be created on the gas pipeline, 4 metres long either side of this point.

I would like to do it automated as possible. I have 60 points to work through, all with varied crossing lengths.

Original question in full:

I have a line layer of pipes and a point layer of where these pipes cross roads, rivers etc. I have already snapped the points to the lines. In the point layer I have a length of these "crossings" e.g a bridge.

I want to be able to "re-section" the pipe line layer so that from the point a bridge of 10 metres would have a new section 5 metres either side of the point of crossing.

I am using Arcmap 10.3 and DO NOT have access to Spatial Analyst.

Comment: Which licence level do you have? Basic, Standard, Advanced?

Comment: thank you for your comment. I did it the buffer option way, not as arduous as I thought it would be. Note to self the way you know how is often the quickest.
and thank you for for reminding me I need to free up the single advanced licence at work. Back to basic I go...